# AVAudioPlayer playing sound with very low volume when WebRTC audio call in progress

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am attempting to play a sound clip using `AVAudioPlayer` while having an active `PeerConnection` using the `GoogleWebRTC` Obj-C library for iOS.

When I play the sound, I can hear it through the speakers, but it plays at an extremely low (almost inaudible) volume in comparison with the WebRTC Audio output.

I have AVAudioSession set to `active = true` with the following; `AVAudioSession.Category = .playAndRecord`, `AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions = [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .mixWithOthers]`, `AVAudioSession.Mode = .voiceChat`.

I have no trouble playing and hearing sounds when there is not an actively configured WebRTC audio connection.

Is there a way to allow sound to play from an `AVAudioPlayer` without it being lowered in volume via WebRTC?

```
do {
        try setActiveAudio()

        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: asset.data, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        activePlayers.append(player)

        player.delegate = self
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
} catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is it possible to post a code snippet of your function call, so others can help figure out what your issue is? Thanks.

Comment: added code snippet

Comment: I am seeing essentially this as well. It is not actually very low volume (at least for me) it is routing the sound playback (from and AVAudioPlayer) through the recevier output (the phone ear piece). I believe this is something to do with the voice processing IO unit inside webrtc

Answer (score 2):

Before play audio, change mode to default, also will lost aec, agc support,

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&error];
```

when finish play, reset mode to voice chat,

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
```

Comment: This is problem with the speakerphone, but when using bluetooth headphones, the mixing level if fine. Now, if I set mode to `default`, it solves the speakerphone issue, but making complete mess when using headphones. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have faced somewhat similar issue, when the ringer is off. Can you

1. Make sure the ringer is not off
2. Make sure the current output port is speaker.

   ```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
   ```

Comment: This issue is still present with ringer on and output override port set to speaker.